# Count rows in multiple columns left to right until specific criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count

I have the following table below.  I will be referencing a specific number based on other extraneous information.  Lets say the specific number is 30.  I first need to count 30 numbers down my September list then move to October then November until count has reached 30.  Then I need to count all the missing values until the next value would reach the 30th count from the previous task.  So for this example the 30th number would be November 19th.  The count of the missing should be 55, November 15th (if I counted that right).  That value would then be stored in a cell.

I obtained the missed days with the following formula: `=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(L$1:INDEX(L:L,N$2)),M$2:INDEX(M:M,COUNT(M:M)+ROW(M$1)),0)),ROW(L$1:INDEX(L:L,N$2))),ROW()-ROW(L$1)),"")` (see table 2 for column reference)

The max column value will be blank if there is no data in the month column, therefore the missed column will also have not data.  I set that up with the following formula:
 `=IF(COUNTA(M:M)>1,31,"")` (see table 2 for column reference)

```
    Table 1    
   September max  missed  October  max   missed   November  max  missed
    1        30   4        1       31    2        2         30   1
    2             6        3             6        7              3
    3             7        4             7        9              4
    5             11       5             8        10             5
    8             12       12            9        11             6
    9             13       15            10       16             8
    10            14       20            11       17             12
    15            16       28            13       18             13
    22            17       30            14       19             14
    23            18       31            16       20             15
    24            19                     17       22             21
    25            20                     18       27             23
    29            21                     19       28             24
                  26                     21                      25
                  27                     22                      26
                  28                     23                      29
                  30                     24                      30
                                         25
                                         26
                                         27
                                         29

    Table 2
    L               M             N         O
    (blank)         September     max       missed
```

I have an idea of how I would write this, but do not know the syntax:

```
    x = Select(Range("G8").Value)    
    'value that holds specific value (30 for above example)

    If x < 31 Then
    '30 days in September

            y = Count(M2:M32) Until = x
            'values in September

            z = Count(O2:O32) Until = value of y - 1
            'What if the last value is the 30th of September, how would you stop on August 31st?

            Range("A1").Value = z
            'value of z is stored in cell A1

                    Elseif x < 62 Then
                    '61 days in September and October

                    y2 = Count(M2:M32) & Count(Q2:Q32) Until = x
                    'Values in September and October

                    z2 = Count(R2:R32) & (S2:S32) Until =value of -1
                    'Again, if the last value is the 31st of October how would you stop on September 30th?

                    Range("A1").Value = z
                    'Value of z is stored in cell A1

                           Elseif
                           'continue for each month (12 times)

    End If
```

There are a couple of things that could cause some problems here with my suggestions (that I just thought of). How would I dictate my starting month?  Lets say I wanted to reference a specific cell and that cell contains the number 4.  So I would want to start in April, even if I had data in March.  Another way of thinking about this is March is in year 2019 and April is in 2018.  So then how could I could I get the code to jump from say December back to January?  Say column Z is December and column A is January.  I wouldn't necessarily want my code to only read left to right.  It would need to start in reference to another cell and then jump back to the start if the year changes.

I apologies for the lengthiness, but that's my best effort in explaining. Let me know if you have any questions or if I can provide anyone with more example, pictures, etc.

Comment: Do you want to make this logics for all months?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reorganize your data table to something like this:

```
Day        Status
01.09.2018 ok
02.09.2018 ok
03.09.2018 ok
04.09.2018 missed
05.09.2018 ok
06.09.2018 missed
07.09.2018 missed
08.09.2018 ok
09.09.2018 ok
10.09.2018 ok
11.09.2018 missed
12.09.2018 missed
13.09.2018 missed
14.09.2018 missed
15.09.2018 ok
16.09.2018 missed
17.09.2018 missed
18.09.2018 missed
19.09.2018 missed
20.09.2018 missed
21.09.2018 missed
22.09.2018 ok
23.09.2018 ok
24.09.2018 ok
25.09.2018 ok
26.09.2018 missed
27.09.2018 missed
28.09.2018 missed
29.09.2018 ok
30.09.2018 missed
01.10.2018 ok
02.10.2018 ok
03.10.2018 ok
04.10.2018 ok
05.10.2018 ok
06.10.2018 ok
07.10.2018 ok
08.10.2018 ok
09.10.2018 ok
10.10.2018 ok
11.10.2018 ok
12.10.2018 ok
13.10.2018 ok
14.10.2018 ok
15.10.2018 ok
16.10.2018 ok
17.10.2018 ok
18.10.2018 ok
19.10.2018 ok
20.10.2018 ok
21.10.2018 ok
22.10.2018 ok
23.10.2018 ok
24.10.2018 ok
25.10.2018 ok
26.10.2018 ok
27.10.2018 ok
28.10.2018 ok
29.10.2018 ok
30.10.2018 ok
31.10.2018 missed
```

After that, you could easily manage your counts, find anything you want via filtering, specifying date start and so on